# Showing the existence of limits.

Tags: category-theory

Suppose I have an adjunction $\mathcal{C}\overset{R}{\underset{I}\leftrightarrows}\mathcal{D}$, where $R\dashv I$, and $I$ is full and faithful.
Now let $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ be any diagram, I then want to prove that if $IF$ has a limit in $\mathcal{D}$, then $F$ has a limit in $\mathcal{C}$.

I suppose I have to start by choosing an arbitrary limit of $IF$ in $\mathcal{D}$ and from that construct a limit of $F$ in $\mathcal{C}$. However, I am not really sure where to go from there.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: $I$ _preserves_ the limit. So there is an obvious candidate...

Comment: But doesn't this only really help me the other way? Doesn't this mean that if $F$ has a limit, then so does $IF$, but not that if $IF$ does, that $F$ does?

Comment: That way around is not true in general. I am going to guess that $I$ is supposed to be fully faithful – then it is true.

Comment: Yes, you are right, $I$ is full and faithful, however, I still don't see how the fact that $I$ preserves limits helps me. Could you throw me another hint perhaps?

Comment: I also figured this out: If $IF(A)$ is a limit in $\mathcal{D}$ then by adjunction, for any object $D$ in $\mathcal{D}$ there is a bijection between $\mathcal{D}(D,IF(A))$ and $\mathcal{C}(R(D),F(A))$. Since $IF(A)$ is a limit there is a unique arrow to it from every $D$ in $\mathcal{D}$ so there also is a unique arrow from every $R(D)$ to $F(A)$. This seems to almost complete the proof but I am left with whether $R$ is neccesarily surjective.

Comment: $R$ is not necessarily surjective, but it is _essentially_ surjective.

Comment: Ok, I tried very hard but I still don't see why it would be essentially surjective. It doesn't seem to be a general property of any adjuctions, and I also dont't see how it follows from the fact that $I$ is full and faithful.

Comment: It does. Show that $R I$ is isomorphic to the identity.

Comment: Ah ofcourse, thanks a bundle for allthe great help!

Comment: Why is the limit of $FI$ necessarily in the image of $FI$? I can't see anything in the definition of a cone, a limit, a fully faithful functor, or an adjoint that suggests it would have to be.